# Как выполнить js в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, javascript

Здравствуйте, уважаемые программисты.

Мне нужно отправить пост запрос на сайте, после отправки запроса (в снифере) выполняется js скрипт, который похоже перенаправляет на другую страницу с некоторыми параметрами которых нет на странице. Загвоздка в том, что ответ сервера на запрос отрицательный, без обработки JS.

Сайт без подключенного JS не работает.

Как подключить JS в Delphi? Работаю через Indy 10.5.5

Я думаю что не требуется отправлять другие запросы, просто должен выполниться скрипт.

Comment: А взять другой снифер и посмотреть что за запрос отправляется после выполнения что-то там в промежуточном снифере нельзя?

Comment: а отправляется get, я его вижу

Comment: v8 попробуйте

Comment: Что это такое? Версия снифера?

Comment: [V8 JavaScript Engine](http://code.google.com/p/v8/).

Или, например, мозилловский [SpiderMonkey](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-javascript/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вариантов несколько:
использовать **TwebBrouser** (или аналог)

посмотреть код скрипта и считать не достающие параметры.

Comment: кода на 1к строк =))